# Unions and their effect on salary with tenure

Tags: barriers-to-entry

I'm wondering if labor unions cause a steeper salary over experience(or tenure) graph. I.e. low salaries in entry positions and very high salaries in tenure positions for union workers vs. similar workers non-unionized.

Comment: Are you looking for an experimental setting to explore if this relationship (if it exists) is causal? Or are you just asking if such a relationship exists?